# Why is this .dll being copied to the output folder?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dll

I have many projects in my solution and, by some reason, when I (Re)Build a certain project, it carries Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll and Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll to the output folder.

I have a reference to Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll, however it is set to Copy Local = False, as are all other references in this project, and as you can see in the image:
[image]

I don't even have a reference to Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll in this project. The Pre-build and Post-build event command line also contains nothing that could cause this. Can someone point any other reason why this could be happening?

**Edit:** removing the reference and (re)building also doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please check reference of this in all other project, what might happening is that this dll is referenced to any other project with Local yes and you are refrencing it in this project. Also try by setting this particular version as false.

Comment: Impossible to diagnose, you'll need to change the MSBuild verbosity to detailed.  Do take this as an opportunity to set the Copy Local property of this assembly reference to True, the user isn't going to have it installed in the GAC like you do.

Comment: @NipunAmbastha I did a check and it before doesn't seen to be the problem, but of course, since it's a lot of projects I may have missed something, I will check again. If there is another possibility I would like to know, thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant Maybe is not the best of practices, but we have a folder with all the necessary .dll references that are not ours (like Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll) and it is added to the installer. So we do not need it to be copied to the output folder, althought it doesn't have bad effects, it's more a matter of curiosity and organization.

Comment: You are right, it is never a good practice to not test the code the way it is going to run on the user's machine.  Also significantly exposes you to the risk that another programmer in your team found a workaround for this installer not copying all required files.  He might have edited a project file by hand to add a Copy task for example.

Comment: Actually the folder with the referenced .dlls is copied to the Output folder and the exe.config file is set to search in that folder for references, so it is tested as it will run in the client; but I got your point, that could be a problem.

Comment: Did you try to remove the bin and obj folders and then building again? Maybe it is from previous build when you did have copy local enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to indirect reference as well. What i mean is, if there is a library that you are referencing in your application, which may need any of these dll's then these are going to get copied over to the bin folder. For ServiceLocation one, may be you are using the Unity framework for IoC.